# Webcam software that can capture still images from multiple webcams?

Tags: images, webcam

I'm working on a project where I with just one mouse click or press of a key on the keyboard, can capture still images from 6 webcams at the same time(or at least within a few seconds) and saving them on a specific location on the computer.

I have found home surveillance software that can display multiple webcams and take still images from them, but only from one at a time.

Does anybody know of a webcam software that can do what I need it to do?

Comment: Which software have you already used, and what alternatives to this software have you found?

Comment: "Webcamxp" and "Multi Webcam video recorder" are two I tried that displays several cams simultaneously but you can only grab a still frame from one at a time. And all other software I have come across seem to be the same.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily roll your own with [OpenCV2](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_table_of_contents_setup/py_table_of_contents_setup.html#py-table-of-content-setup) and [Python](http://python.org) - some examples that you should be able to build on are [here](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html).

- Free
- Cross platform
- Fully customisable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try and look into it, although I only have a little experience with programming for Arduino.

Comment: @H2C You should have fun.